# Biopython can't download file even if pdb exits

Tags: biopython

I am trying to use biopython with python3 to download pdbs automatically. However for a few pdbs I have the problem that I get an 404 error.

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

One example for which it isn't working but should is: 4YUU
The pdb file exits in the database and I don't see any differences to the pdbs biopython downloaded. Any help would be appreciated.

The code is used:

```
import Bio
from Bio.PDB import PDBList
pdbl=PDBList()
pdbl.retrieve_pdb_file('4YUU')
```

Comment: Please show your code -- it will help trouble shoot as well as show others that you have made an effort to solve this on your own.

Comment: Sorry, I added it. The code seemed just too basic to me to share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF format file for 4YUU really does't exist, goto http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=4YUU for 4YUU (Crystal structure of oxygen-evolving photosystem II from a red alga), and under both the "Display Files" and "Download Files" menus the PDB format entry is greyed out.

Without looking into this further I would guess this is a very large protein or there is something else which cannot be represented in the legacy older text based PDB file format.

Try downloading the PDBx/mmCIF file instead via the website, which Biopython should be able to parse.

Note that the next release of Biopython (which will be Biopython 1.69) has changes the PDBList download code to support this.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination! That was really helpful. :)